# Polar Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have a polar differential equation (this is the reduced variant) as:

$$r' = 0, \theta' = 1$$

I figured out (from previous answers) that I can nicely convert this to Cartesian and use StreamPlot as:

```
  field = {0, 1};

  TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", field, {r, \[Theta]} -> {x, y}]

  StreamPlot[{-(y/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]),x/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]},{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},
   StreamColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

This generates the correct phase portrait and worked great. I was even able to animate it.

My question now is how can this field (polar DEQ) be solved as a polar DEQ? Can't this be solved as such and plotted using polar plots to arrive at the same phase portrait?

Am I missing something? I tried NDSolve without luck, so think I must be missing something basic here. Is something special required for polar type DEQs in Mathematica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your aim is just to solve this specific  system:

```
{rd, an} = {r[t], s[t]} /. 
      First@DSolve[{r'[t] == 0, s'[t] == 1, r[0] == radius, 
         s[0] == 0}, {r[t], s[t]}, t]
f[u_, tm_] := 
 CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {rd, an}] /. {radius -> u,t->tm}
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[f[j, t], {j, Range[4]}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

where $\theta$ is represented by s and I have assumed $\theta(0)=0$ for simplicity.

Animating (uniform circular motion):

[image]

Comment: Excellent! How did you do the animated uniform motion graphic?

Comment: @Amzoti I exported the following as an animated gif `Table[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[f[j, t], {j, Range[4]}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi},Epilog->(Point[{f[#,k]]&/@Range[4])],{k,Range[0,2Pi,0.1]}]` This takes some processing time. You could randomise the starting position etc.

Comment: Is there a syntax issue with the commented Table command? Regards

Comment: Yes. Sorry. correction: `Table[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[f[j, t], {j, Range[4]}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi},Epilog->(Point[{f[#,k]}]&/@Range[4])],{k,Range[0,2Pi,0.1]}]`

Comment: Is it possible to use something like PolarPlot so no conversion to Cartesian is necessary?